# Jekyll Installation Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, jekyll

I'm trying to install Jekyll on my mac, it was not happening at all so I tried to reinstall my rvm 1.9.3. But I am getting following error now. It will be great if some one can help me to fix this.

```
...
e.rb, skipping
Installing ri documentation for parslet-1.5.0
unable to convert U+00E5 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for test/test_child.rb, skipping
Installing ri documentation for posix-spawn-0.3.8
unable to convert U+2014 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/pygments/popen.rb, skipping
unable to convert U+00F8 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for test/test_pygments.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xC5" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for         vendor/pygments-main/AUTHORS, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for     vendor/pygments-main/CHANGES, skipping
unable to convert U+2219 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII for vendor/pygments-    main/tests/examplefiles/coq_RelationClasses, skipping
unable to convert "\xE9" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for     vendor/pygments-main/tests/examplefiles/example.cpp, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for         vendor/pygments-main/tests/examplefiles/fucked_up.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for     vendor/pygments-main/tests/examplefiles/py3_test.txt, skipping

RDoc::Parser::Ruby failure around line 1 of
vendor/pygments-main/tests/examplefiles/ruby_func_def.rb

Before reporting this, could you check that the file you're documenting
has proper syntax:

/Users/mauliks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby -c vendor/pygments-        main/tests/examplefiles/ruby_func_def.rb

RDoc is not a full Ruby parser and will fail when fed invalid ruby programs.

The internal error was:

(NoMethodError) undefined method `name' for #    <RDoc::RubyToken::TkLPAREN:0x007fa58bfdcf68>

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `name' for #<RDoc::RubyToken::TkLPAREN:0x007fa58bfdcf68>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I fixed that,

```
gem install rdoc --pre
```